# elements of the quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $Q$ is the ideal $\{3a+b(1+\sqrt{-5}) 
\mid a, b \in \Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}] \}$ in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}$], for the quotient ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]/Q$, how can I compute its distinct cosets.

I can only write the form of them is $\{ (c+3a)+b(1+\sqrt{-5})\mid a, b, c \in\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]\}$ (Some additional information says that there are only three distinct cosets)How can I keep going with the problem?

Also, I always consider the elements in quotient ring as the remainder, because I start studying the quotient ring with $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ whose elements is just the possible remainders. However, for some complicated quotient ring, this method would not work, does anyone have any general methods for finding elements in quotient ring?

Comment: Elements of $Q$ are of the form $a+ b \sqrt {-5}$ where $a \equiv b\ (\text {mod}\ 3).$

Comment: So I think there are altogether $6$ elements in the quotient ring.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{AMScd}\newcommand\Ker{\operatorname{Ker}}$Let $\pi:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ be the canonical projection and $X$ an indeterminate over $\Bbb Z$.
There exists one and only one ring homomorphism $\varepsilon:\Bbb Z[X]\to\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ such that $\varepsilon(X)=-1$.
There exists one and only one ring homomorphism $\nu:\Bbb Z[X]\to\Bbb Z[i\sqrt 5]$ such that $\nu(X)=i\sqrt 5$.
Then $\Ker\varepsilon\supseteq(X^2+5)\Bbb Z[X]=\Ker\nu$, hence there exists one and only one ring homomorphism $\psi:\Bbb Z[i\sqrt 5]\to\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ making the following diagram commutative:
\begin{CD}
\Bbb Z@>\pi>>\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\\
@VVV@AA\psi A\\
\Bbb Z[X]@>>\nu>\Bbb Z[i\sqrt 5]
\end{CD}
Moreover, $\psi$ is surjective and
$$\psi(a+i\sqrt 5b)=a-b+3\Bbb Z$$
for every $a,b\in\Bbb Z$, so that $\Ker\psi=\mathfrak q=\{3a+b(1+\sqrt{-5}) 
\mid a, b \in \Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}] \}$.
Thus we get a ring isomorphism
$$\bar\psi:\Bbb Z[i\sqrt 5]/\mathfrak q\xrightarrow\sim\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$$